# 'if playback doesn't begin shortly try restarting your device'

Tags: android-webview, youtube-iframe-api

'if playback doesn't begin shortly try restarting your device' youtube javascript player not working android 4.4.2. how can i solve it?.Thanks

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: if you find a solution comment this post? thank you

Comment: I had made a demo app which was working earlier but now I am getting error. https://github.com/vkdinventor/chatheads If i find any solution I will let you know. I think youtube has changed something.

Comment: ok thanks . If i find a solution i will write to you

Comment: I tested https://github.com/vkdinventor/chatheads on marshmallow and it is working.

Comment: but dont working on lolipop

Comment: can u find asolution?

Comment: No I haven't find

Comment: :( dont play in service.Problem in service